# Is it possible to create an array whose size is based on the number of lines in a file?

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a VBA script which reads a text file, then creates a array of its contents.

Currently I have to specify the size of the array. Is there a way to have the size of the array dependent on the number of lines in the text file?

```
Sub WriteToArray()

Const strFileName As String = "C:\Users\km933\Documents\Excel Macro\Keyword_File.txt"
Dim PR(1 To 20)
Dim intFileNum As Integer
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim strRecordData

intFileNum = FreeFile
intCount = 1
Open strFileName For Input As #intFileNum
Do Until EOF(intFileNum) Or intCount > 20
    Input #intFileNum, strRecordData
    PR(intCount) = strRecordData
    intCount = intCount + 1
Loop

MsgBox PR(1)

Close #intFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow do people still use VB?

Comment: unfortunately yes, very few alternatives to MS Excel and macros

Comment: by the way: it is not vb script and also not VB ... it is VBA. There are major differences between all of that 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically change the size of an array with ReDim. If you want to keep the already added entries, you can use ReDim Preserve.

```
Sub WriteToArray()

    Const strFileName As String = "C:\Users\km933\Documents\Excel Macro\Keyword_File.txt"
    Dim PR() As String
    Dim intFileNum As Integer
    Dim strRecordData As String

    intFileNum = FreeFile

    Open strFileName For Input As #intFileNum

    ReDim PR(0)

    Do Until EOF(intFileNum) Or intCount > 20
        Input #intFileNum, strRecordData

        ReDim Preserve PR(UBound(PR) + 1)
        PR(UBound(PR)) = strRecordData
    Loop

    MsgBox PR(1)

    Close #intFileNum

End Sub
```

only problem is in that example that PR(0) is not used ... but with a little bit of additonal effort this would also be possible. The example is only reduced to the basic concept.

And of course you should define your variables not as variant!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read everything then split in a single pass:

```
dim PR() as String

open "C:\Users\km933\Documents\Excel Macro\Keyword_File.txt" for Input as #1
    PR = Split(Input$(LOF(1), #1), vbCrLf)
close #1

for i = 0 To ubound(PR)
    debug.? i, PR(i)
next
```